# Getting error in using echo statement in php?

Tags: php

i have use this code to display image from database, but it shows syntax error.. here is my backend code.

```
<?php
        echo ' <div id="ib-main-wrapper" class="ib-main-wrapper">';
        echo ' <div class="ib-main">';
        $sql_select = "select * from tbl_photo";
        $sql_select =  mysql_query($select_image);
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_select)){

                echo "<a href="#"><img src='".$path.$data['photo']."' data-largesrc='".$path.$data['photo']."' /><span>".$data['photo']."</span></a>";
        }
        echo '</div></div>';
        ?>
```

It's static code is:

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/upload/Desert.jpg" data-largesrc="images/large/Desert.jpg" alt="image01"/><span>Crabbed Age and Youth</span></a>
```

kindly give answer..

Comment: What error did you get ?

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "<a href="#">
              ^----- here it is
```

Try this instead:

```
echo "<a href=\"#\">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quotation was wrong.

```
 echo '<a href="#"><img src="'.$path.$data['photo'].'" data-largesrc="'.$path.$data['photo'].'" /><span>"'.$data['photo'].'"</span></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the prob:  `echo "<a href="#">`

Here is the solution

```
 echo ' <div id="ib-main-wrapper" class="ib-main-wrapper">';
    echo ' <div class="ib-main">';
    $sql_select = "select * from tbl_photo";
    $sql_select =  mysql_query($select_image);
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_select)){

            echo "<a href='#'><img src='".$path.$data['photo']."' data-largesrc='".$path.$data['photo']."' /><span>".$data['photo']."</span></a>";
    }
    echo '</div></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo "<a href="#"><img src='".$path.$data['photo']."' data-largesrc='".$path.$data['photo']."' /><span>".$data['photo']."</span></a>";
```

To

```
echo '<a href="#"><img src="'.$path.$data['photo'].'" data-largesrc="'.$path.$data['photo'].'" /><span>'.$data['photo'].'</span></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape quotes using `\`.  Without escaping these characters you were creating an unterminated String literal.

```
echo "<a href=\"#\"><img src=\"".$path.$data['photo']."\" data-largesrc=\"".$path.$data['photo']."\" /><span>".$data['photo']."</span></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you could use *heredoc* and *newdoc* syntax (which are very similar to *single quote* and *double quote*) to specify a string literal, I recommend using **single quotes** when specifying HTML code, since HTML are full with *double quotes*, and you don't want to escape all of them.

When you use *single quotes* you don't have to escape the *double quotes* inside the string literal:

```
echo 'This works "just fine"';
```

The drawback in this type of specification, that variables won't get expanded, like in *double quoted* text, so you will have to concatenate each variable with a `.` (dot).

```
echo 'This works'.$justfine;
```

While using *double quotes* you could do the following:

```
echo "This works $justfine";
```

These are the most important differences between *single and double quotes*.
If you would like to learn more, you may consider reading about [Strings in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). It's better to clarify these things, because you will use them a lot.